# UIPress Shift + L is only registered as Shift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In my app that supports keyboard shortcuts, I have implemented this to track keyboard presses:

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
  guard presses.count == 1, let press = presses.first, let key = press.key else { return }
  // handle
}
```

The problem is that a few keys (like L, K, R) don't work with Shift (both left and right behave the same). When I press Shift + L, it's only registered as Shift (`key.keyCode.rawValue` is 225, and modifiers set is empty). Other keys work well with Shift.

This VC will be embedded in a SwiftUI view, I'm using a US bluetooth keyboard on a real device.

Any idea why this is the case and how to solve it? Due to the app setup, other ways of keyboard shortcut handling don't work well.

Comment: Please update your question with specific details about how you are testing this. Is this on a real iPad with an external keyboard? Or is this with an iPad simulator? If a simulator, what I/O Keyboard settings do you have setup for the simulator? Also, what locale does your app report? What kind of keyboard are you using? When I test your posted code in a simple view controller, I get the expected results. Do you have any other code in your app that could be handling the L, K, and R keys?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the question with more info

Comment: @SonNguyen The point is that you have not shown us how to reproduce your "issue". Provide a [mcve]. It should be both minimal and reproducible.